# How to merge cells in Spotfire Table chart for output rows

Tags: spotfire

I am displaying a report in the form of Table chart in Spotfire. I will state my requirement with an example. Typically in table chart when data is displayed they will be repeated for each and every value of the query. What is want is that repetitivie data to be merged when displayed in table chart like this:

[image]

Hope my expalnation is clear and will update if more is rqd. but need help to achhieve this for my requirement.

Comment: Did that work for you @direwolf

Comment: @scsimon: It was very simple and it simply worked by adding all the columns in the category axis. But if the number of columns exceed the page ,i am not able to scroll there. can you check if you have the same issue

Comment: The behavior is the same. One problem with this though is you lose the ability to sort on the columns

Comment: ok. But i got my requirement but its not scroll able, how to enable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is to use a `CROSS TABLE` versus a `TABLE`. On your Category Axis, place your `COLUMN1` and `COLUMN2`, and what ever other columns you want, or aggregations, on `VALUE AXIS`. The "Merging" of cells strictly for formatting isn't something that's really done, but a this is the simplest way outside of a custom `HTML TABLE`